# Solving a Linear IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I need help solving this linear Initial value problem: $$y'=-L(y(t)-\phi(t))+\phi'(t) \\ y(0)=y_0$$ where $\phi(t)=\cos(30t)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts on this problem? What have you tried, and where are you having difficulty? This will help people write an appropriate answer the addresses your problem. Questions that include this information tend to have a much better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the differential equation as $$y' + Ly = L\cos(30t) - 30\sin(30t), \qquad \qquad (1)$$ we first solve the homogeneous part of the differential equation $$y' + Ly = 0$$ and so have a complementary function of $$Y_{CF} = Ae^{-LT}.$$

We look for a particular integral that satisfies the differential equation of the form $y_{PI} = B\sin(30t)+C\cos(30t)$. We have $y'_{PI} = 30B\cos(30t) - 30C\sin(30t)$ and plugging into $(1)$

$$30B\cos(30t) - 30C\sin(30t) + LB\sin(30t)+LC\cos(30t) = L\cos(30t) - 30\sin(30t).$$

Comparing coefficients, $$30B + LC = L$$ $$LB - 30C = -30$$ $$\implies C = 1, \qquad B = 0.$$

So the general solution is the superposition of the complimentary function and the particular integral $$y_{GS} = Ae^{-Lt} + \cos(30t).$$

Finally we apply our initial condition to find the constant $A$.

$$y_{GS}(0) = A + 1 = y_0 \implies A = y_0 - 1.$$

This gives us the solution

$$y(t) = (y_0 - 1)e^{-Lt} + cos(30t),$$

as required.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, again rewriting your differential equation as $$y' + Ly = L\cos(30t) - 30\sin(30t)$$

taking the Laplace transform and expanding into a partial fraction decomposition gives

$$Y(s) = \dfrac{y_0s^2 + Ls + 900y_0 - 900}{(s^2 + 900)(s+L)} = \dfrac{A}{s+L} + \dfrac{Bs+C}{s^2+900}.$$

$$\implies y_0s^2 + Ls + 900y_0 - 900 = A(s^2 + 900) + (Bs+C)(s+L)$$

Choosing $$s = -L: \quad y_0(L^2 + 900) - (L^2+900) = A(L^2+900), \quad \therefore \quad A =  y_0 - 1$$
$$ s = 0: \qquad\qquad900(y_0 - 1) = 900(y_0 - 1) + LC \quad \qquad\qquad \therefore C = 0.$$

Finally comparing the $s^2$ coefficients we must have that $y_0 = y_0 - 1 + B \implies B = 1.$

So our decomposition is

$$Y(s) = \dfrac{y_0-1}{s+L} + \dfrac{s}{s^2+30^2};$$

and clearly from our tables

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(Y(s)) = y(t) = (y_0 - 1)e^{-Lt} + \cos(30t),$$

which tallies with the previous answer.